# how can I define a variable as being equal to a variable of different type?

Tags: type-conversion, modelica, dymola

Ok, so I have something like this:

```
model MolarAmount
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  SI.AmountOfSubstance nu "moles of stuff";
  parameter Real lambda = 42 "some variable on which nu depends";

equation
  nu = 1 - lambda;
end MolarAmount;
```

This runs just fine, but it complains about incompatible units, as expected.  How do I get it to ignore this?

Answer (score 1):

That is odd.  I always thought that Dymola threated literals (`1`) and variables without units (`lambda`) as wildcards in the unit checking.  You might try setting the `units` attribute on `lambda` to be "1" (I thought that was the default).  You might also take a look at the diode model in the standard library.  It uses a parametric formulation that has to address this kind of unit checking problem as well.

Sorry for not validating any of these suggestions.  I don't really have a copy of Dymola handy to test with.

HTH

Comment: I think the actual expression I WAS using in the code did not have any literals so that may be why it worked differently than you expected.  Unfortunately, I am no longer using the section of code that caused this problem so I can't easily check this. It's probably somewhere in my git history, but I can't easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Dymola are you running? Dymola 2015 (2014-04) accepts this model.

I would guess setting `lambda(unit="mol")` would solve your problems. It also leads to less magic in the unit checking.

Comment: My example was not the exact code I'm having a problem with.  In the actual code, the expression is a polynomial so a simple fix like this won't work.